# How to add authentication to Azure storage blob upload

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, blob, azure-storage

I'm trying to upload images to Azure Blob Storage. I'm using .Net Core and Azure.Storage.Blobs v12.8.0.

The following code is what I have so far.

```
try
    {
    var documentByteArray = // a valid byte array of a png file
    var blobUri = new Uri("https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/images/myfile.png");

    BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(blobUri);

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(documentByteArray))
    {
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true, default);
        await blobClient.SetHttpHeadersAsync(new BlobHttpHeaders
        {
            ContentType = "image/png"
        });
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //
}
```

...but somewhat predictably it fails with the exception `Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.`. I say predictable because I've not added any authentication...

And this is the problem/question. How do I add authentication so it will upload?

I know there are Access Keys that I can use - but how? I can't find any examples in MS documentation.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the Azure Portal, you can get the connection string of the storage account (under "Access Keys" section).

Once you have the connection string, you can use the following code:

```
var connectionString = "your-storage-account-connection-string";
var containerName = "images";
var blobName = "myfile.png";

var blobClient = new BlobClient(connectionString, containerName, blobName);
//do the upload here...
```

Other option is to use storage account name and access key (again you can get it from Azure Portal). You would do something like:

```
var accountName = "account-name";
var accountKey = "account-key";
var blobUri = new Uri("https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/images/myfile.png");
var credentials = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
var blobClient = new BlobClient(blobUri, credentials);
//do the upload here...
```

You can find more information about BlobClient constructors here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you for the help :o)

Answer (score 0):

You should upload your blob through a CloudStorageAccount instance, like this:

```
var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
    new StorageCredentials("<your account name>", "<your key>"),
    "core.windows.net",
    true);

var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the code above is for the older SDK and not version 12.8.0 used by OP.

Comment: thanks for quick answer, but @GauravMantri is correct, unfortunately this is for an older version